# Lifting of Reflexivity

Tags: banach-spaces

I am looking for a proof (the simple the better) of the Theorem stating that $L_p(E)$  is reflexive if and only if $E$ is reflexive.
Here is $E$ a Banach space and $L_p(E)$ is the Lebesgue-Bochner space of strongly measurable functions with their p norm integrable. For me finite measures will do

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE! Please show us what you have tried on this problem for us to better understand what we need to specifically address